# Arithmetic operation in xpath on array of elements

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a requirement to sum amount from every element i have in my response using **xpath**
,however condition is i am not sure about how many tags I am going to get in my response.
Sum= amount1*value1+ amount2*value2+amount3*value3+....

```
<root>
  <element>
   <amount>10</amount>
   <value>2</value>
  </element>  
  <element>
   <amount>20</amount>
   <value>2</value>
  </element>  
  <element>
   <amount>30</amount>
   <value>2</value>
  </element> 
</root>
```

can some one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below XPath to get summ of all `amount` nodes:

```
sum(//element/amount)
```

Considering updated question:

```
sum(//element/sum(./amount * ./value))
```

Comment: Hey Thanks,just modified my questions a bit,could you please help?